# Android connects to multiple WiFi networks

Tags: android, virtual, android-wifi, adhoc, android-wireless

Is there exists any application to make android connects to multiple WiFi networks at the same time, may be something like virtual Wifi that makes wifi card looks like many but virtually, like this http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/connectify-convert-windows-7-into-virtual-wifi-router/ but this for PC?

If No, is it possible to do something like that as I work on an application that needs the ability to join two wireless networks( ad-hoc and wifi one to get internet connection) simultaneously?

Comment: im not sure, but i dont think it is possible for you to have two open connections to different wifi networks